# Internal server error with Apache 2.4 in .htaccess on WAMP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp

The Apache 2.4 documentation mentions .htaccess as a valid context for using the `<FilesMatch>` directive, with, for example, a `Require all denied` in it.
Ref: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#filesmatch
Yet, it leads to a **500 Internal Error** if I place it in an .htaccess, and no error if I place it in the main configuration file.

However, it seems like it is less the FilesMatch directive that is a problem than the Require all denied, as no errors occurs if I leave the former empty.

Example of the block that I use:

```
<FilesMatch "[\._](htaccess|passwd|inf|ini|inc|cls)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Any idea of how to make it work in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Just saw that the apache error log says: .htaccess: Require not allowed here. I don't know it this is a WAMP implementation shortcoming, or is it the Apache documentation that is not accurate.

Comment: It is nothing to do with WAMPServer, this is all Apache